# How to access the row values of a series in Pandas when doing a vectorized operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sparse/wide dataframe with millions of rows but that can roughly be summarized like this:

```
d = {
    "year" : [2019, 2020, 2021],
    2018 : [True, True, False],
    2019 : [True, False, False],
    2020 : [False, False, True],
    2021 : [False, False, True]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

And I want to create some additional boolean columns based on certain conditions.  When I do this:

```
df['consecutive'] = df[df['year']] * df[df['year'] - 1]
```

I get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1`

but when I hardcode the year like so:

```
df['consecutive'] = df[2019] * df[2018]
```

I get the results as expected:

```
    year    2018    2019    2020    2021    consecutive
0   2019    True    True    False   False   True
1   2020    True    False   False   False   False
2   2021    False   False   True    True    False
```

My previous implementation on a smaller dataset uses df.apply() but performance is an issue here, so the vectorized approach is important.  Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: `df[df['year']] * df[df['year'] - 1]` will give u 4 columns, but u r assigning it to 1 column. That is why error

Comment: You probably want something like `df.iloc[:, 1:-1].to_numpy() * df.iloc[:, 2:].to_numpy()`

Comment: Do you only need to only check years 2018 and 2019 for being consecutively True/False, or you want to to check your every column?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I want to check many different conditions with this approach, the consecutive case is only one example

Comment: Just to clarify, what I'm trying to do is access the value in the year column to use in the calculation for consecutive, and have it return only one column signifying if the 'year' was consecutive or not for that row.

Comment: It is clunky and I haven't thoroughly tested but it looks like this does it:
`df['consecutive'] = [df[df['year'].loc[x]][x] * df[df['year'].loc[x] - 1][x] for x in df.index]`
Anyone have any better ideas?